# tracking execution of long running trigger in postgres using a log table

Tags: postgresql

I have some long running triggers that perform very lengthy calculations. I want to provide some visibility of what is going on by inserting into a log table, essentially an archived version of raise warning.
Problem I have is that the records show up only on trigger completion, is any way I could achieve this?

I originally replaced the Raise warning with this insert into login table for my two trigger, funny thing is that one of the triggers was behaving like this until today, the other no. Either that or we were all suffering some type of hallucination.

I have tried to use a save point and Begin / END block within trigger with no luck, like this

```
create or replace function test_and_drop() returns integer
    cost 10
    language plpgsql
as
$$
    DECLARE
        i integer;
    BEGIN
        for i in 1..10 loop
            begin
            insert into administration.logging_activity values(
                clock_timestamp(), 'xxx', i, 'test', 'RUNNING', 'test', .0);
                PERFORM pg_sleep(5);
            end;
        end loop;
        return i;
    END;
$$;
```

EDIT
I have got a less than ideal solution that seems to work fine.

Based on the above simplified code it would be something like this:

```
create or replace function test_and_drop() returns integer
    cost 10
    language plpgsql
as
$$
    DECLARE
        i integer;
    BEGIN
        for i in 1..20 loop
            PERFORM dblink('host=167.71.00.000 port=5432 dbname=ekfc user=postgres password=000000000000000',
                    format( 'insert into administration.logging_activity values(%L, %L, %L, %L, %L, %L, %L)',
                         clock_timestamp() , '2023-02-29-XXX-098189598535351', i, 'testing', 'RUNNING', 'Pricing proposal', 0.1));
            PERFORM pg_sleep(5);
        end loop;
        return i;
    END;
$$;
```

Comment: The above is not a trigger function as it does not `RETURN trigger` per [plpgsql trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html).  Nor do I see any `CREATE TRIGGER ...` statement.

Comment: The actual trigger is several hundred lines long, I am trying to get this to work first.

Comment: I cannot replicate. You will not be able to see the log entries in another session until the function completes

Answer (score 0):

It is not an ideal solution, but this works for me within my constraints and may be useful to someone else on a similar predicament.
I tested and it works fine, of course using the password is ugly as hell, and not too safe.

````
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE log_progress(username varchar, pricing_id varchar, version integer, caller varchar, status varchar, message varchar, percentage float)
    language plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    PERFORM dblink('dbname=ekfc password=O6c04N9sffssfswrGt1ertbhT9',
        format( 'insert into administration.logging_activity values(%L, %L, %L, %L, %L, %L, %L)',
            clock_timestamp() , pricing_id, version, caller, status, message, percentage));
END;
$$;

create or replace function test_and_drop() returns integer
    cost 10
    language plpgsql
as
$$
    DECLARE
        i integer;
    BEGIN
        for i in 1..5 loop
            CALL log_progress( 'postgres', '2023-02-29-XXX-098189598535351', i, 'testing', 'RUNNING', 'Pricing proposal', 0.1);
            PERFORM pg_sleep(5);
        end loop;
        return i;
    END;
$$;

select test_and_drop();
```## Heading ##
````